# vb.net Download file and unzip it

Tags: vb.net, zip, compression

i want to download a file .zip in vb, and decompress it when download have reached 100%, here is my code to download the file:

```
WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(http://google.zip), "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\google.zip")
        sw.Start()
```

What i need to add to decompress google.zip when download have reached 100%?

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim saveAs as string="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\google.zip"
            Dim theResponse As HttpWebResponse
            Dim theRequest As HttpWebRequest
            Try 'Checks if the file exist
                theRequest = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl) 'fileUrl is your zip url
                theResponse = theRequest.GetResponse
            Catch ex As Exception
            'could not be found on the server (network delay maybe)
            Exit sub 'Exit sub or function, because if not found can't be downloaded
            End Try
            Dim length As Long = theResponse.ContentLength
            Dim writeStream As New IO.FileStream(saveAs, IO.FileMode.Create)
            Dim nRead As Integer
            Do
                Dim readBytes(4095) As Byte
                Dim bytesread As Integer = theResponse.GetResponseStream.Read(readBytes, 0, 4096)
                nRead += bytesread
                If bytesread = 0 Then Exit Do
                writeStream.Write(readBytes, 0, bytesread)
            Loop
            theResponse.GetResponseStream.Close()
            writeStream.Close()
            'File downloaded 100%
```

Unzipping the file is simple-> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx